# How to make blocking tcp socket with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I work with `QTcpSocket`. I need any write/read calls to the socket to be synchronous (blocking).

I know there is `waitForReadyRead()` and `waitForBytesWritten()`, but those two methods are marked in Qt documentation as they can fail randomly under Windows. I cannot affort this.

The blocking read is the most important (as reading comes always after writting a command to the other peer, so I know that if data reaches the other peer, it will answer).

I have tried 2 approaches.

**First:**

```
QByteArray readBytes(qint64 count)
{
    int sleepIterations = 0;
    QByteArray resultBytes;
    while (resultBytes.size() < count && sleepIterations < 100)
    {
        if (socket->bytesAvailable() == 0)
        {
            sleepIterations++;
            QThread::msleep(100);
            QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);
            continue;
        }

        resultBytes += socket->read(qMin(count, socket->bytesAvailable()));
    }
    return resultBytes;
}
```

This should wait for bytes to be available for reading on the socket, processing the event loop in the mean time, so the socket is doing it's necessary internal stuff.

Unfortunately - for unknown to me reason - the `bytesAvailable()` sometimes returns correct number of bytes, but sometimes it never returns anything greater than 0.

I know in fact that there was data to be read, because it used to work with the second approach (but it has it's own problems).

**Second:**

I have a kind of signal "blocker", which blocks current context and processes event loop, until certain signal is emitted. This is the "blocker":

SignalWait.h:

```
class SignalWait : public QObject
{
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        SignalWait(QObject *object, const char *signal);

        bool wait(int msTimeout);

    private:
        bool called = false;

    private slots:
        void handleSignal();
};
```

SignalWait.cpp:

```
SignalWait::SignalWait(QObject* object, const char* signal) :
    QObject()
{
    connect(object, signal, this, SLOT(handleSignal()));
}

bool SignalWait::wait(int msTimeout)
{
    QTime timer(0, 0, 0, msTimeout);
    timer.start();
    while (!called && timer.elapsed() < msTimeout)
        QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);

    return called;
}

void SignalWait::handleSignal()
{
    called = true;
}
```

and then I used it like this:

```
SignalWait signalWait(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()));
// ...
// socket->write(...);
// ...
if (!signalWait.wait(30000))
{
    // error
    return;
}
bytes = socket->read(size);
```

This approach seems to be working better, but it also fails from time to time. I don't know why. It's like the `readyRead()` signal was never emitted and the `SignalWait` keeps waiting, until it times out.

I'm out of ideas. What is the proper way to deal with it?

Comment: I'm not convinced that you really need a blocking socket.  What prevents you from using non-blocking operations?  (The problem with blocking I/O is that it prevents the GUI from doing things like handling mouse events, and thus leads to a poor user experience, unless you do all of your I/O in separate threads, in which case there isn't a whole lot of reason to use a QTCPSocket instead of just plain old BSD sockets API)

Comment: Socket works in it's own thread, so GUI interaction is not an issue. Actually the code should also be workin in non-GUI application (GUI is optional). It (blocking) is necessary, because the code that uses it assumes those calls to be blocking and it's not a subject of change.

Comment: In that case maybe just call socketDescriptor() on the QTCPSocket to get the underlying socket/file descriptor, and use the BSD Sockets API (i.e. send() and recv()) rather than QTCPSocket calls.  That way you don't have to deal with QTCPSocket's non-blocking-io-oriented design.

Comment: I don't know how all other programs that use QtSocket work on Windows, but apparently they do. Qt authors recommend using readyRead signal but you are doing it wrong. Connect the signal once per socket, not every time you want to read. Use bytesAvailable() to see how many bytes are there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to use the asynchronous approach but if you really want to go with the synchronous way, then a better way is to use a local event loop:

```
QTimer timer;
timer.setSingleShot(true);
QEventLoop loop;
loop.connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(quit())); 
connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));

while (resultBytes.size() < count)
{
    timer.start(msTimeout);
    loop.exec();

    if(timer.isActive())
        resultBytes += socket->read(qMin(count, socket->bytesAvailable()));
    else
        break;
}
```

Here it waits until `count` bytes are read or the the timeout reaches.

Comment: Can timer signal be connected on same eventloop as readyRead signal (in this case on QEventLoop loop)?

Comment: @MilanKocic I am not sure what you mean exactly but you can connect `timeout` signal to any other signal or slot with no argument.

Comment: i asked can we do this: loop.connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(quit())); loop.connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(quit()));